# How can I use or operator here to make my code shorter?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code. How can I use 'or' operator here to make my code shorter?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#id_event_type_1").click(function(){
            $("#id_end_date").show();
            $('label[for="id_end_date"]').show();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#id_event_type_2").click(function(){
            $("#id_end_date").show();
            $('label[for="id_end_date"]').show();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#id_event_type_3").click(function(){
            $("#id_end_date").show();
            $('label[for="id_end_date"]').show();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since they seem to do the same:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_event_type_1,#id_event_type_2,#id_event_type_3").click(function(){
        $("#id_end_date").show();
        $('label[for="id_end_date"]').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$(function() {
    for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
        $("#id_event_type_" + x).click(function(){
            $("#id_end_date").show();
            $('label[for="id_end_date"]').show();
        });
    }
});
```

I don't know what your markup looks like, but it's easier to just change the loop end number than keep adding to that string (after a few more entries it'll be hard to look at).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery **starts with** `^=` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("[id^=id_event_type]").click(function(){
        $("#id_end_date").show();
        $('label[for="id_end_date"]').show();
    });


}); //END $(document).ready()
```

The **starts with** selector works like this: `$([attribute ^= string])`, allowing you to specify ALL elements with `id` or `class` or `name` or `??` that *start with* the specified string.

---

When using **starts with**, you can also split-out the specific attribute string of the element clicked on like this:

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2CWEc/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

        <style>
            div {height:100px; width:100px; margin:20px;}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("[id^=id_event_type]").click(function(){
        var myid = $(this).attr('id');
        var num = myid.split('_')[3];
        alert('You clicked on: ' +myid+ ', which is number ' +num);
        $("#id_end_date").show();
        $('label[for="id_end_date"]').show();
    });


}); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <div id="id_event_type_1" style="background-color:red"></div>
    <div id="id_event_type_2" style="background-color:blue"></div>
    <div id="id_event_type_3" style="background-color:green"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

One final point. You don't need to enclose each routine in its own (document).ready() function. You only need the one, and then each routine can be listed, one after the other, inside that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#id_event_type_1").click(function(){
        $("#id_end_date").show();
        $('label[for="id_end_date"]').show();
    });

    $("#id_event_type_2").click(function(){
        $("#id_end_date").show();
        $('label[for="id_end_date"]').show();
    });

    $("#id_event_type_3").click(function(){
        $("#id_end_date").show();
        $('label[for="id_end_date"]').show();
    });
}); //END document.ready()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#id_event_type_1, #id_event_type_2, #id_event_type_3").click(function(){
        $("#id_end_date").show();
        $('label[for="id_end_date"]').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {  
    $('[id^=id_event_type_]').click(function(){
        $("#id_end_date").show();
        $('label[for="id_end_date"]').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need 1 document.ready event, there's no need to repeat it.
Also, I'd consider giving those items a class, and simply using a class selector for your click event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".eventType").click(function(){
        /* do whatever */
    });

});
```